# What was the first operating system called DOS?

Tags: history, operating-system, mainframe, terminology, minicomputers

MS-DOS a.k.a. PC-DOS nee QDOS, was commonly just referred to as DOS. But 'disk operating system' is a very obvious acronym; there must have been previous operating systems so called.

What was the first operating system called DOS?

Comment: Lol I always thought DOS meant "dirty operating system"

Comment: I always thought D(isk) was a strange way to start the acronym. I mean, the OS is operating so much more than the disk. "Disk operating system" sounds more like disk controller firmware than an actual operating system.

Comment: @ThomasCook, given that MS-DOS/PC-DOS was based on QDOS, which was "Quick and Dirty OS", you were right.

Comment: **D**isplay **O**n **S**creen

Comment: @dwizum - it's not that the System is Operating the Disk, it is that the Operating System is Disk-based, in contrast to the many predecessors which were not disk-based (and probably ran on computers which had no disks - because disks were expensive luxuries).

Comment: @RayButterworth - well, that's another question (maybe you should post it?).  Who came up with the name "PC-DOS" - IBM or Microsoft?  If IBM, I think it most likely that the men in suits named PC-DOS in the same way that they had named DOS/360,, DOS/VS, DOS/VSE -- in which case it's D for Disk.

Comment: @another-dave IBM came up with the name PC DOS.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[DOS/360](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/360/dos/)

(As distinct from TOS/360, the tape OS)

Announced at the end of 1964 [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS/360_and_successors).

Comment: So, "DOS: The Original Series" _aka_ TOS :D

Comment: That's interesting! Etymonline which in my experience as a language enthusiast is actually pretty good, lists the first use of ***DOS*** as 1967.

Comment: "Announced" is not the same as "available to customers". The Wikipedia link says delivered in June 1966, so there's still a slight discrepancy.